# cakephp 3.0 composer installation issue

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

After executing

```
php composer.phar create-project -s dev cakephp/app
```

I receive the following problem

> Problem 1
>
> - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Problem 2
>
> - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Problem 3
>
> - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires php >=5.4.19 -> no matching package found.

NB:

- I have php 5.4.4 installed
- I have composer updated to the latest commit
- OS : MAC MAVRICX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message reads:

> cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires php >=5.4.19

But

> I have php 5.4.4 installed

php 5.4.4 is not >= 5.4.19, cannot be used, and cannot be upgraded via composer hence the error output. The solution to this is to install a version of php that *does* satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score -2):

first install php5-intl than go for composser

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl

  Note: This is required.

Step 1 cd /ldc/home/

Step 2 curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: This is not addressing anything in the question.